# Passing arguments to bash -c with spaces

Tags: bash, shell, spaces

I have the command line arguments to a program stored in a bash array and one of the arguments can have spaces in it. `X=(A B "C D" E)`

I have another constraint that I need to execute my program through a `bash -c` statement. (Technically it is a `... | xargs bash -c "./a.out ..."` statement)

When I do this, I end up mangling the spaces in my command. How can I do this correctly?

I wrote a quick c++ program to output command line arguments to represent my program

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
        std::cout << '"' << argv[i] << '"' << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am looking to get the output from `./a.out "${X[@]}"`

```
"A"
"B"
"C D"
"E"
```

but when I test this `bash -c "./a.out ${X[@]}"` I just get just get

```
"A"
```

and when I test this `bash -c "./a.out ${X[*]}"` it mangles the spaces and I get

```
"A"
"B"
"C"
"D"
"E"
```

What can  Ido?

Comment: BTW, I'd argue that this is a special case of BashFAQ #50; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: BTW, do you want my answer to go into *why* your attempts behave the way they do, as opposed to only discussing the Right Thing?

Comment: (Speaking of the Right Thing, an easier test program to show arguments in literal form would be a bash script with one line after the shebang: `printf '%q\n' "$@"`; you could use `'"%s"\n'` to get equivalent behavior to your existing C program, but that output format is ambiguous as arguments can contain both quotes and newlines).

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a read. I was playing around with IFS trying to get the spaces not to mingle but that just felt wrong. My coworkers just said "get rid of spaces" but that felt like a lost opportunity to learn.

Comment: If the goal is to learn, I'll expand the answer to go into detail about how the things you tried behave.

Comment: thank you. i would appreciate that. I learned from the bash man page that `"${X[*]}"` was putting the first IFS char between arguments and forming a large string from that and that `"${X[@]}"` was forming a list of `"${X[1]}"` `"${X[2]}"` `"${X[3]}"`. I appreciate your time.

Comment: Do you actually *need* to use `-c`? Would `bash ./a.out "${X[@]}"` work instead?

Comment: Good point. Actually, why not just `xargs ./a.out` without any bash involved at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The Right Way(s)

### Passing data out-of-band from code

Since you're using `xargs`, consider passing data through the argument list of the shell itself, not inside the script passed with `-c`:

```
xargs bash -c './a.out "$@"' _
```

Because the `"$@"` is itself in single quotes, it isn't expanded by the parent shell, but instead by the child shell that's passed other arguments by xargs. (The `_` is there to act as a placeholder for `$0`).

This is actually a best practice even in cases where the number of arguments is fixed: It the potential for shell injection attacks via malicious data substituted directly into your script text.

---

### Using `printf %q` to create `eval`-safe content

ksh, bash, and zsh include a `%q` operator to `printf` which quotes content in an `eval`-safe manner:

```
printf -v out_str '%q ' "${X[@]}"
bash -c "./a.out $out_str"
```

---

## Why The Wrong Ways Didn't Work

### `bash -c './a.out "${X[@]}"'`

When `"${foo[@]}"` is expanded *inside* a string, the result is an array with contents before that expansion prepended to the first element, additional elements prior to the last one emitted standalone, and any contents of the string after the last one appended to the last element. Thus `bash -c "./a.out begin${X[@]}end"` expands to:

```
bash -c "./a.out beginA" "B" "C D" "Eend"
```

...thus, `B`, `C D` and `E` are all passed to your shell, but outside of the `-c` argument; they can be accessed with `"$@"`, or looking at `$1`, `$2`, etc.

---

### `bash -c './a.out ${X[*]}'`

By contrast, with `"${foo[*]}`, the result is the first character of IFS (by default, a simple space) being substituted between each array element. Thus:

```
bash -c "./a.out ${X[*]}"
```

...becomes...

```
bash -c "./a.out A B C D E"
```

...such that the space literal between `C` and `D` becomes indistinguishable from the literal spaces placed between other characters by the expansion process.

Comment: Oooh. I missed that you were using xargs. The best practice, then, is to not substitute into your generated script content at all. I'll expand a little to make that more explicit.

Comment: oh thanks.  I've just been playing around more with printf testing out commands such as `printf "'%q' " "./a.out begin${X[@]}end"` to see the output of your examples

Comment: I think I've got this answer as complete as it needs to be for the moment -- let me know if anything is missing or unclear.

Comment: X is not an input to xargs but instead a parameter telling my a.out how to behave. For example I have been turning seconds since midnight into a epoch timepoint so I have an outer loop over dates where I populate X with the midnight epoch seconds and effectively echo all the time offsets through xargs into a.out which will add the correct midnight to each one.

Comment: Gotcha. Mind you, you could run `... | ./xargs a.out "${args[@]}" --` (assuming your program respects the POSIX-recommended `--` sigil for end-of-options).

Comment: BTW, if you're not using either `\0` or `-d $'\n'` arguments to `xargs`, let me add a somewhat-off-topic note to strongly recommend them (particularly the former, if you can use NUL delimiters) if your list of arguments is programmatically generated; the default parsing behavior by `xargs` is less than ideal in most cases.

Comment: so you recommend something like the following `printf '20151101\x0020151102\x00' | xargs -d '\x00' -I '%%' echo '%%'`

Comment: @JamesAndrews, `printf '%s\0' 20151101 20151102 | xargs -0 echo` would be a far easier way to write that. In general, I'd also argue that the `-I` argument to `xargs` is best avoided absent a compelling reason; the 255-byte limit... ick.

Comment: :) thanks for that. It certainly looks simpler. I really appreciate this post. I've learned a ton